# single text file on require multiple operations using a shell or bash script

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

**My Source File : Test.txt**

Note : File is a tab delimited and few columns doesn't have column names:

```
Chr  Start  End   Alt   Value
Exo  0      10    .     1.50    .   20:-2     30:0.9    50:50   50
Exo  1      20    .     1.50    .   20:-1     30:-1     50:50   50
Exo  2      30    .     1.50    .   20:0.02   30:0.9    50:50   50
Exo  3      40    .     1.50    .   20:-1     30:-2     50:50   50
Nem  3      40    .     1.50    .   20:-1     30:-2     50:50   50
```

**On above file trying to achive below file operations like :**

1) Column 7 & 8 need to do split by **':'** and It require to give column names after changing like "mod1", "mod2","mod3", "mod4".

2) After that move splitted columns next to the "Value" columns and put one more "Comment" column next to "mod4" (In that comment column blank data needed).

3) Filter Column "Mod2" by all the values more than 0.01 gets deleted

**And Final Result need to store in output folder like** :

```
Chr  Start  End   Alt  Value  mod1  mod2  mod3  mod4  comment 
Exo  0      10    -1   1.50   20    -2    30    0.9           -1  50:50  50
Exo  1      20    -1   1.50   20    -1    30    -1            -1  50:50  50
Exo  3      40    -1   1.50   20    -1    30    -2            -1  50:50  50
```

I tried below's and achieved few operations some are remaining:

```
#!bin/bash

cd /home/uxm/Desktop/Shell/

# Replace the only dots (.) by -1

awk -F'\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/^\.$/,"-1",$i)}} 1' OFS="\t" Test.txt | tail >> Test1.txt

# splitted 7th no column by delimitted ":" 

awk '{ split($7, a, ":"); print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"a[1]"\t"a[2]"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11 >> "testfile1.tmp"; }' Test1.txt;
mv testfile1.tmp Test2.txt;

# splitted 8th no column by delimitted ":" 

awk '{ split($9, a, ":"); print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"a[1]"\t"a[2]"\t"$10"\t"$11 >> "testfile2.tmp"; }' Test2.txt;
mv testfile2.tmp Test3.txt;

# Give name to splitted columns

awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NR==1{$11="nCol\tMod1\tMod2\tMod3\tMod4"}1' Test3.txt >> Test4.txt

# Filter data by "Exo" word 

awk -F'\t' 'NR==1;{ if($1 == "Exo") { print }}' Test4.txt | tail >> Test5.txt
```

Comment: We're not a script-writing service. What have _you_ tried so far?

Comment: with a combination of `sed` and `awk` you can complete most of this, as roaima said, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think that sample bash script would have gotten very far with `$FPath=./test.xt;`

Comment: @Kramer : Ok, I will try same sed and awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an `awk` script that does the steps that you enumerate. Doing all operations in one script has the benefit of not having to run `awk` multiple times and store intermediate results in files or variables.

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "\t" }
NR == 1 {
    # Add new column headers

    # First four "mod" headers
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
        $(NF + 1) = "mod" i

    # Then a "comment" header
    $(NF + 1) = "comment"

    # Output and continue with next input line
    print
    next
}

# Ignore lines that don't have "Exo" in the first column
$1 != "Exo" { next }

{
    # Working our way "backwards" from column 13 down to 1

    # Shift the last two columns right by three steps
    $13 = $10
    $12 = $9

    # Set column 11 to column 6, or to -1 if it's a dot
    if ($6 == ".")
        $11 = -1
    else
        $11 = $6 

    # Empty the comment column
    $10 = ""

    # Move column 8 into column 9
    $9 = $8

    # Split column 9 into columns 8 and 9
    split($9, a, ":")
    $9 = a[2]
    $8 = a[1]

    # Split column 7 into columns 6 and 7
    split($7, a, ":")
    $7 = a[2]
    $6 = a[1]

    # Column 5 remains unmodified

    # Put -1 in column 4 if it's a dot
    if ($4 == ".") $4 = -1

    # Columns 1, 2, 3 remains unmodified   
}

# Output if we want this line
$7 <= 0.01 { print }
```

Running it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk Test.txt
Chr     Start   End     Alt     Value   mod1    mod2    mod3    mod4    comment
Exo     0       10      -1      1.50    20      -2      30      0.9             -1      50:50   50
Exo     1       20      -1      1.50    20      -1      30      -1              -1      50:50   50
Exo     3       40      -1      1.50    20      -1      30      -2              -1      50:50   50
```

I assumed from your own code that you're only interested in the `Exo` lines, so I made the script only look at these. And I assumed that any dot in tha `Alt` column (and in the original first nameless column) should be changed to `-1`, also by looking at your code.

Comment: Thanks @Kusananda : Output columns are not getting properly.

Chr     mod1t   mod2    mod3    mod4e   comment
Exo     0       10      -1      1.50    20      -2      30      0.9             -1      50:50   50
Exo     1       20      -1      1.50    20      -1      30      -1              -1      50:50   50
Exo     3       40      -1      1.50    20      -1      30      -2              -1      50:50   50

Comment: First I tried separate awk execution for understanding awk, once I will reach to final result, I will merge this all code in single awk execution and in single script.

Comment: @RaviJ Is your input file created on a Windows system? If so, run `dos2unix` on it first.